# Any ideas why my jQuery won't execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotator

I started building a testimonial rotator for a project. Oddly enough it broke before it made it live (tested it prior) and I decided to scrap it and write a new script to perform the same task. I'm relatively new to jQuery and I'm not the most familiar with using ternary operators but I wanted to give that a shot.

The code below is what I'm working with. It's my belief that this code should execute properly however if you were to copy the entirety of it into a new .html doc you'll see it doesn't.

I'm looking for any help I can get. I'm always trying to grow as a developer - I'm not one to just copy and paste blindly to get a result. I like to know what's going on :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Rotator Testing</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #testimonials{
            width:300px;
            height:100px;
            background:#666;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;left:0;
        }
        .testimonial{
            color:#CCC;
            display:block;
            width:200px;
            height:30px;
            background:#333;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;top:0;
            z-index:5;
        }
        .show{
            z-index:10;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.testimonial').css({opacity: 0.0});
            $('.testimonial:first').css({opacity:1.0});
            setInterval(function(){

                var current = ( $('#testimonials .testimonial.show')? $('#testimonials .testimonial.show') : $('#testimonials .testimonial:first'));
                var next = current.next().length ? $('#testimonials .testimonial:first') : current.next();

                //Set the fade in effect for the next testimonial, show class has higher z-index
                next.css({opacity: 0.0})
                .addClass('show')
                .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

                //Hide the current testimonial
                current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
                .removeClass('show');


            },2000);
        });
    </script>



</head>

<body>

    <div id="testimonials">
        <article class="testimonial">Testimonial 1</article>
        <article class="testimonial">Testimonial 2</article>
        <article class="testimonial">Testimonial 3</article>
        <article class="testimonial">Testimonial 4</article>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It should work properly but it doesn't" is a horrible description of what you expected and how the actual behavior differ. Would you accept that kind of bug report from you users?

Comment: and here's a nudge http://jsfiddle.net/4adTQ/1/

Comment: The first answer below fixes the ternary which I'm thankful for. However it looks like there might be an issue that determines which testimonial is next because the same testimonial fades in and out over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var current = ( $('#testimonials .testimonial.show')? $('#testimonials .testimonial.show') : $('#testimonials .testimonial:first'));
```

jQuery will always return an object(even if the selector  doesn't match any element), so  your condition:

```
$('#testimonials .testimonial.show')
```

...will always be true.

Check the length instead:

```
   var current = ( $('#testimonials .testimonial.show').length)
                    ? $('#testimonials .testimonial.show') 
                    : $('#testimonials .testimonial:first');
```

---

the next issue:

```
var next = current.next().length ? $('#testimonials .testimonial:first') : current.next();
```

I guess you need to switch this to:

```
var next = (!current.next().length) 
            ? $('#testimonials .testimonial:first') 
            : current.next();
```

Currently you select the .next() if it is empty.

Comment: +1 correct, to get it working he also needs to invert the ternary expression for `var next`

Comment: Thank you guys I really appreciate the help this looks to have fixed my issues and I know how to approach this next time. :)